# Find a KeyValuePair inside a List

Tags: c#, list

Suppose I have

```
 List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> d
```

I know the string but I want to find its integer.
How do I find the keyvaluepair inside this List?

Comment: Yeah, but I just need the keyvaluepair object. from then I can get the integer (key member). I ask in the question: "I know the string but I want to find *its integer*".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'd write this:

```
var result = d.Where(kvp => kvp.Value == "something");
```

`result` would contain all the `KeyValuePair`s with a value of `"something"`

Answer (score 5):

You could use `LINQ` `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` if the item is unique:

```
KeyValuePair<int, string> v = d.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Value == "mystring");
int key = v.Key;
```

If the item is not unique, then you could use `LINQ` `Where`:

```
var v = d.Where(x => x.Value == "mystring"); //the results would be IEnumerable
```

And if the item is not unique, but you want to get the first one among the non-unique items, use `First` or `FirstOrDefault`

```
var v = d.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "mystring");
int key = v.Key;
```

Answer (score 3):

One of the many possible solutions:

```
   List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "a"),
                    new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "b")
                };

    var pair = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "b");
    // or you can also use list.Find(x => x.Value == "b");

    Console.WriteLine(pair.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(pair.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
d.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Value == "yoursearchvalue").Key;
```